# Why is this property not enumerable?

Tags: javascript

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 1
  prop2: 2
  prop3: null
  prop4: undefined
}

//These (above code) all appear in for in loop below 
let obj2 = Object.create(obj, {
  prop5: {
    value: 5
  }
});

//this (above code) does not appear 
for (let prop in obj2) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

I get prop1, prop2, prop3, & prop4 not prop5. Why is         prop5 not enumerable? (ie doesn’t show in a for in loop)? But the rest do. Why are prop1-4 enumerable by default and prop5 is not. Sorry I’m brand new to coding hope I explained question well

Comment: Because you didn't pass `enumerable: true` to `prop5`'s descriptor? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: For more information, read [Object.create documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`

Comment: But I didn’t pass it to the other properties either, what makes prop5 unique? I thought if I don’t modify the properties, the enumerable, writable, & configurable are true by default